# Can you avoid out of range error if you use range based for loop instead of the standard for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, outofrangeexception, range-based-loop

I was experimenting around with **range-based** for loop found that if you use range-based for loop to loop through a vector it runs into **out of range** error is there any way to avoid this error if you are using **range-based** for loop

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> num{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    for (auto i : num)
    {
        cout << num[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

it shows this error

[image]

Comment: It should be `cout << i << endl;`

Comment: Here you do `cout << num[num[0]] << endl;`, which is problematic for last element

Comment: I tend to not use name `i` here, as we might expect `i` for index as you do, `for (auto elem : num)` seems better.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid 'out of range' if you are aware of what you're doing. Did you check what values are assigned to `i` in such `for` loop...? Test with a vector e.g. `{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: Thanks a lot I saw the issue with my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the type of loop. Your loop looks at all the values `i` inside the vector `num`, then it prints `num[i]`. One of them is `5`, so it prints `num[5]`. But `num` has 5 elements so they only go up to `num[4]`. Out of range.

Comment: Thanks alot you cleared up my misunderstanding @user253751

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class It>
struct indexer {
  It it;
  It operator*()const{return it;}
  void operator++(){++it;}
  void operator++(int){++it;}
  bool operator==(indexer const& o)const{ return it == o.it; }
  bool operator!=(indexer const& o)const{ return it != o.it; }
};
template<class It>
struct range {
  It b,e;
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
};
range<indexer<std::size_t>> counting( std::size_t begin, std::size_t end ) {
  std::cout << begin << "->" << end << "\n";
  return {{begin}, {end}};
}

template<class X>
auto indexes_of( X const& x ) {
  using std::size;
  return counting(0, size(x));
}
```

now I can make your code do what you thought it did:

```
vector<int> num{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
for (auto i : indexes_of(num))
{
    cout << num[i] << endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/MEqqKfKx4).

Your problem was mistaking indexes into the vector for the elements.  Range-for returns the elements.  `indexes_of` makes it return the indexes for the container in question.

Comment: thanks for showing me a detailed example @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont